# Password changed, but only accepts old password at login

Tags: 12.04, login, password

Yesterday evening I changed my password, using: **Systems Settings >> User Accounts**

But, this morning my **new** password is not accepted. In trying other solutions, I tried my **old** password which still allowed me to login.

Please can anyone give me reason why this happen, and how I can stop this happening?

Comment: Have you tried changing it a second time? Maybe you didn't successfully change it the first time.

Comment: @Huckle tried now in CLI way . but failed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you will need to do.. Lines starting with '$' are prompts, you don't type the '$'. Lines without the '$' are output, you don't type them either. Things inside <> should be replaced with your new or old password as indicated.

```
$passwd
Enter the new password (minimum of 5, maximum of 8 characters).
Please use a combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers.
Old password: <old password goes here>
New password: <new password goes here>
Re-enter new password: <new password goes here>
Password changed.
```

Comment: man i have tried CLI also but its not accepted , but you did man .now i have tested by locking screen and new password accepted that . after a restart i will make the final report

Comment: I didn't fully understand your last comment. Did you, or did you not, get the same output as you see in my answer? If not, what output did you get (put it on pastebin). If yes, is there anywhere your new password does not work?

Comment: the thing is , you did it man successfully . I have tried both CLI way and GUI way but they havent update new password . but its working after trying your's . thanks man :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. On an unrelated note, no one says 'man' anymore. If they did, it would the phrase would go "man, you did it successfully" or even better "It was successful! You did it, man!" The 'man' is like an interjection and it belongs in its own clause. The sentence should read the same with and without the 'man'

Comment: i am not good with English because its not my mother tongue (i know reasons are not the answer and not recommended of course )and i am using it in my daily life (as a primary) from 4 years .So i think need more time . I am sorry for my mistakes but thanks for suggesting me ,the right way of using .

Answer (score 1):

> Please can anyone give me reason why this happen, and how I can stop this happening?

This should **NOT** happen on a normal system. Try changing your password again, and then check it out immediately by trying a command which requires `sudo`, e.g. `sudo apt-get update` -- the new password is the one that should work.

Comment: tried but failed still  old password ,even after changing 2nd time .

Comment: Try in the terminal with `passwd`, and paste the output of `ls -l /etc/passwd`

Comment: its saying like Bad command  ,here is the output  raja@badfox:~$ cat ls -l /etc/passwd
cat: invalid option -- 'l'
Try `cat --help' for more information.

Comment: somebody could help me on this. please

Comment: @Raja, why did you use `cat`? Just type `ls -l /etc/passwd` at the prompt -- no cat. Please also pastebin the contents of `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DTP9kq1Q

Answer (score 0):

> Please can anyone give me reason why this happen, and how I can stop this happening?

As far as I understood, there is a difference if you command

- `sudo passwd <your username>`, which is equivalent to the bare `passwd` suggested above, and
- `sudo passwd` which changes the password of the *root* user.

It gets confusing with Ubuntu, because usage of the root user is actually minimized (you could use `sudo su -u` to become a fully-fledged one).

If this is correct, you had changed the root password but not your log-in password.